# Selecting a big list with specific combination of values from the same SQL table

Tags: sql

I would like to search in sql table and take as a result the rows
that have the specific pair of values in 2 different columns.

In a table like that

```
A   | B
----+----
a1  | b1
a2  | b5
a3  | b2
a4  | b3
a5  | b5
```

I am looking for the pairs ( a1,b1, ) , (a2,b5) and (a3,b2).

I was thinking to do something like this

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE t.a in ( a1 , a2 , a3 ) 
  AND t.b in ( b1,b5,b2 )
```

but this returns all the possible combination of the 2 lists that are given as input.

Then I saw that this working

```
SELECT ...
FROM ... 
WHERE  (t.a = a1 AND tb = b1  ) 
   OR  (t.a = a2 AND tb = b5  ) 
   OR  (t.a = a3 AND tb = b2  )
```

However this SQL command can become really big as the number of the search objects increases (and in my case I have a big number of search pairs)

So I was wondering if you have a better SQL query to suggest?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: load your search pairs in a temp table then join your table to your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the tuples:

```
select ...
from ...
where (a,b) in ( ('a1','b1'), ('a2','b5'), ('a3','b2') );
```

You didn't state your DBMS, but the above is ANSI standard SQL

Comment: Thanks! it looks much better.